# Apache 500 error configuration

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm currently trying to configure my server so that any missing pages will gracefully error out on a 404 custom page. Unfortunately, everything appears to be erroring to a 500 Internal Server Error.

My site settings in my server (not using .htaccess) are:

```
AllowOverride All

RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

if I type domain.com/missingpage - all I get is a 500 error. Would really appreciate the guidance here. Thank you

Comment: Every 500 error is accompanied with a line in the error log that explains what went wrong.  What does the error log say?

Comment: @Charles "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace." - It appears to be looping and not instead of gracefully failing at 10, it's dying and erroring out.

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the ErrorDocument directive?  If you visit 404.php directly, do you get the correct result?  What happens if you visit a different PHP script that exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asume you are visiting `/misssing-page` on your server. It is not a file nor a directory so it's being rewritten to `/misssing-page.php`. It looks more like a file now but still does not exist on server, so for apache it's still neither a file nor a directory and it's being rewritten once again to `/misssing-page.php.php`. This goes on 10 times as your log says and results in internal server error.

So you are missing one condition, something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.php$
```

So the rewrite will only occur when there is `.php` at the end of the requested uri

Comment: Absolutely perfect result!!! Thank you so much